# how to implement simple uppy fileuploader

Tags: javascript, file-upload, uppy

this simple example does not work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Uppy File Uploader Example</title>
  <link href="https://releases.transloadit.com/uppy/v3.7.0/uppy.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    

    <!-- 2. Initialize -->
    <div id="uppy"></div> 
    <script type="module">
      import { Uppy, DragDrop } from "https://releases.transloadit.com/uppy/v3.7.0/uppy.min.js"
      const uppy = new Uppy()
      uppy.use(DragDrop, { target: '#uppy' })
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

```
Uncaught SyntaxError SyntaxError: The requested module 'https://releases.transloadit.com/uppy/v3.7.0/uppy.min.js' does not provide an export named 'DragDrop'
    at (program) (c:\Users\belos\source\repos\testUppy\index.html:14:22)
```

i tried to change names and check docs but it does not work i did not find any solution

Comment: Tried the basic example code from their site myself and got the same result... I would say they have a bug in that version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import {
    Uppy,
    Dashboard,
    Webcam,
    Tus,
} 
from "https://releases.transloadit.com/uppy/v3.10.0/uppy.min.mjs";
```

I changed link from which is writen in docs to link here and it solved my issue

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).